# Gradient of the dual function for a nonlinear program

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, duality-theorems

I'm attempting to find a proof for a property from Floudas' Nonlinear and Mixed-Integer Optimization book. Consider a nonlinear optimization problem of the form
\begin{align}
 \min_{{\bf x}}&\quad f({\bf x})\\
  \nonumber \text{subject to } \quad&{\bf h}({\bf x}) = {\bf 0}\\
  \nonumber \quad&{\bf g}({\bf x}) \le {\bf 0}\\
     \nonumber \quad&{\bf x}\in {\bf X}
\end{align}
where ${\bf X}$ is a nonempty convex set. No assumptions on ${\bf h}$ or ${\bf g}$ are made. Form the partial Lagrangian of the above problem as
\begin{align}
L({\bf x},\lambda,\mu) = f({\bf x}) + \lambda^T{\bf h}({\bf x}) + \mu^T{\bf g}({\bf x})
\end{align}
The dual function is formed as
\begin{align}
\phi(\lambda,\mu) = \inf_{{\bf x}\in{\bf X}}L({\bf x},\lambda,\mu)
\end{align}
Define the set ${\bf Y}(\lambda,\mu) = \{{\bf x}^*:{\bf x}^* \text{ minimizes }L({\bf x},\lambda,\mu)\text{ over }{\bf x}\in {\bf X} \}$.

***Property (4.2.3 - Differentiability of dual function)***
Let $f({\bf x})$, ${\bf h}({\bf x})$, ${\bf g}({\bf x})$ be continuous functions, and ${\bf X}$ be a nonempty compact set. If the set ${\bf Y}(\bar\lambda,\bar\mu)$ reduces to a single element at the point $(\bar\lambda,\bar\mu)$, then the dual function $\phi(\lambda,\mu)$ is differentiable at $(\bar\lambda,\bar\mu)$ and its gradient is 
\begin{align}
\nabla\phi(\bar\lambda,\bar\mu) = ({\bf h}({\bf x}^*),{\bf g}({\bf x}^*))
\end{align}

---

My attempt at a solution:

Let 
\begin{align}
{\bf x}^*(\lambda,\mu) = \arg \min_{{\bf x}\in{\bf X}}L({\bf x},\lambda,\mu)
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\phi(\lambda,\mu) = f({\bf x}^*(\lambda,\mu)) + \lambda^T{\bf h}({\bf x}^*(\lambda,\mu)) + \mu^T{\bf g}({\bf x}^*(\lambda,\mu))
\end{align}
I'm having difficulty forming the gradient of the above. Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

In [this lecture](http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Grundutb/CTH/tma521/0607/fo3.pdf) there is a proof of this proposition, using arguments from convex analysis. The "meat" of the proof starts in page 28, but you should read all the lecture to understand the notation, definitions and such.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm looking for a more official source (e.g. a book, or a peer-reviewed document). Also, I fail to see how slide 28 is relevant, it mentions that the set of solutions $X(\mu)$ is compact (we already have, by assumption, that $X(\mu)$ is a singleton). Slide 32 mentions that $\nabla q(\mu) = g(x)$ for every $x\in X(\mu)$; however, it requires different (stronger?) conditions that the ones stated in the original post.

Comment: Well, yes. I agree in that there can be better, neater references (and hopefully somebody else finds one such). Then again I think the proof in those references should be pretty similar (although, much better looking) than the proof in the link I sent. I'd be *really* surprised if a proposition like this can be proved without using arguments and notions from convex analysis like convex subdifferentials. (though I'd love to see one such a proof).

Comment: To explain a bit why I think the link is useful: Page 28 is important because, given the asumptions from original post, it gives a characterization of the [convex subdifferential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) $\partial q(\mu)$ of $q$. Now, why is this important?. Because of the following: if a convex function $q$ is continuous at a certain $\mu$ and its convex subdifferential $\partial q(\mu)$ consists of only one point $v$, we can conclude $q$ is actually differentiable and $\nabla q(\mu)=v$. Which is what is used in page 32, based on what is proved at page 28.